# Javascript addition and subtraction with a string value

Tags: javascript

I recently went through this typecast JS question:

Given `'11'+10`, the answer is `1110`. It is clear that is not `21` because one is a string and JavaScript will treat both as string and perform concatenation instead of mathematical addition.

Why is `'11'-10` is equal to `1`, instead of something else?

Comment: because there's no other operation to do with `-` aside from subtraction and every operands in javascript is considered as a number first before doing anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the subtraction operator is not ambiguous and is only defined for numbers. Hence both operands are converted to numbers first.

See the specification:

- [Addition](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1)
- [Subtraction](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.2)

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.daaq.net/old/javascript/index.php?page=js+operators&parent=core+javascript) is the answer to your question:

It says

**If you have a plus sign between a number and a string, concatenation takes precedence over addition. All other numeric operators, when one operand is a string and the other a number, will attempt to convert the string to a number**

Check `String Operators` section on the link.

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert on JavaScript, but your question presents a great opportunity to learn from and read through the [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/).  This is version 5.1, so it will do fine for this question. [Section 11.6.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.2) covers the Subtraction operator:

> The production AdditiveExpression : AdditiveExpression - MultiplicativeExpression is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating AdditiveExpression.
> 2. Let lval be GetValue(lref).
> 3. Let rref be the result of evaluating MultiplicativeExpression.
> 4. Let rval be GetValue(rref).
> 5. Let lnum be ToNumber(lval).
> 6. Let rnum be ToNumber(rval).
> 7. Return the result of applying the subtraction operation to lnum and rnum.

So, for step 1:

> - Let lref be the result of evaluating AdditiveExpression.

In your case, that is evaluating '11'. We have lref = '11'.

> - Let lval be GetValue(lref).

Per line 1 of [GetValue (V)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1), if Type(V) is not Reference, return V.  Therefore, we return '11'.

We have lval = '11'.

> - Let rref be the result of evaluating MultiplicativeExpression.

In your case, that is 10. We have rref = 10.

> - Let rval be GetValue(rref).

Again, applying line 1 of [GetValue (V)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1), if Type(V) is not Reference, return V. Therefore, we return 10.

We have rval = 10.

> - Let lnum be ToNumber(lval).

lval = '11'. Calling ToNumber('11') will follow the [ToNumber specification for Strings](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3.1), case 1.  There are optional whitespaces surrounding the numeric literal itself. Since your example has no whitespace, the result is simply the numeric literal, which is 11.

We have lnum = 11.

> - Let rnum be ToNumber(rval).

rval = 10. Calling ToNumber(10) will follow the [ToNumber specification for Number](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3).  In that case, the input argument itself is returned, and no conversion occurs. That means we return 10.

We have rnum = 10.

> - Return the result of applying the subtraction operation to lnum and rnum.

One more time, per the specification:

> The - operator performs subtraction when applied to two operands of numeric type, producing the difference of its operands; the left operand is the minuend and the right operand is the subtrahend. Given numeric operands a and b, it is always the case that a–b produces the same result as a +(–b).

We have rnum - lnum = 11 - 10 = 11 + (-10) = 1.

Answer (score 1):

Because of `+` is a operator overloading to contact a string and `-` operator not basically use with the string.

Using `-` string will convert into integer and in `+` case string will concate.

Answer (score 1):

In JS `+` in also concatenate operator, so if the first variable string then  `concatenate operator` priority high

`-` is only mathematical operator so it provide you subtract result.

Answer (score 1):

`+` sign is used for both Number and String concatenate. So it considers as two string concatenate when it found string first. You can use `+` prefix or `Number` to convert string to number

But `-` sign is used for subtraction only applicable to number. So it automatically converts string to number.

Following will solve your issue

```
(+'11') + 10
(+'11') - 10

(or)

 Number('11') + 10
 Number('11') - 10
```

Comment: That's not what the question is about though.

Answer (score 1):

> '+' operator is the only airthmatic operator which also used in case for concatinate string. So when a string and integer found it acts as concatination operator. All other airthmatic operator like -, *, / are only for calculation that is why they treat everything as number like:

```
'20' * 3= 60
'20'/ 2= 10
'20'-5= 15
'20'+ 3 = '203'
```

Answer (score 1):

The addition + is used first for string concatenation (if at least one operand is string) and in other cases as numbers arithmetical addition.
The subtraction always converts the operands to numbers.
Check [this article](http://rainsoft.io/javascriptss-addition-operator-demystified/) for more details about addition operator.